# switching from sqlite to postgres in rails app I´m working on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, rubygems, chartkick

I am rather new to rails and I was thinking about how much trouble is it to switch from sqlite to postgres in an app that I´m currently working on. The thing is I have never switched in a middle of the building App process.

My local database has some data, but it is not relevant and may be deleted. I´m more concerned about the tables, columns, models, etc...

My reasons for the switch are:

1. I want to be able to use the 'groupdate' gem with my 'chartkick' gem in developement.
2. Later I will deploy to Heroku, I have done that before with adding 'pg' gem to production.

I have Postgres installed on my computer and I also have Postgres.app. I´ve been testing chartkick with groupdate in another project, so Postgres is not the problem.

So the question is basically, how much trouble is to switch from sqlite to PG in a middle of a project and what is the easiest and fastest way to do it?

sorry for the long text, hope someone reads it :)

Comment: The easiest way is to start with PostgreSQL :) It is very hard to say otherwise because ActiveRecord doesn't offer any useful database portability so it could be a simple matter of adjusting `Gemfile` and `database.yml` or it could be a big mess if you've accidentally assumed SQLite-specific behavior.

Comment: it seems that you have done most part of it .and in fact there is not much trouble . You simply need to do some database configuration , add "pg" gem in your gemfile. Note that the active-record code is database-agnostic: it will run in MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and others.

Comment: Thanks alot. I managed to do this switch and it was very easy to do. Don´t know what I was so scared of :). I basically followed this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?autoplay=true  but skipped the Taps part since my previous data didn´t matter.